# Mixamo to Blender to Mixamo problem

Tags: texturing, materials, .fbx, obj, mixamo

I have a character model made from Polycam. Imports fine as .OBJ into Mixamo, but I took an FBX to Blender, deleted the armature, and modeled an object to go in character’s hand. I’ve exported as .Obj and FBX but Mixamo is now showing the model as all white. Where are the materials?

Comment: I've had this problem before. Did you pack the materials before exporting?

Comment: Not that I know of, because what’s that?  I’m a Blender noob. But I do understand that Mixamo likes to take zipped .OBJ folders that contain several files. I don’t really understand what all the files are though. I know there is the 3D object, a few .jpgs, and a .mtl. Would I need to prepare a zip folder with all thise somehow from Blender??

Comment: [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)